# Determine the stability of a fixed point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Consider $x'=f(x)$, where 
$f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=-x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for every $x\neq 0$.

How to determine the stability of the fixed point $x^*=0$?

Comment: You could try to draw a phase diagram!!

Comment: @AnishDarnal, I should do this without drawing graphs (analytically).

Comment: A *phase diagram* (already mentioned, one wonders why the OP refuses to use one) shows readily that for every $x_0\ne0$, $x(t)\to \ell(x_0)\ne0$ hence $x^*=0$ is not stable. "Analytically", the initial condition $x_0$ is between two successive zeroes of the function $t\mapsto\sin(1/t)$ and $\ell(x_0)$ is one of these zeroes, depending on the sign of the sine on this interval.

Comment: For example, if $x_0=2/((4n+1)\pi)$ for any nonnegative integer $n$ then $x(t)\to1/((2n+1)\pi)\ne0$.

Comment: @Did According to the standard definition $x^*$ is *stable* in this problem. Although not *asymptotically*.

Comment: @Artem Indeed, Lyapunov stable but not asymptotically stable.